# Fastest way to Add Image into Video using FFMPEG at First 20 Seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

Anyone knows the fastest way to add image into video at first 20 seconds?
I have tried it, but it seemed like FFMPEG re-encoded the whole video even after 20 seconds which took a long time..

here my code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=5:5:enable='between(t,0,20)'" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fast

Use a faster [`-preset`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) and [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) the audio instead of re-encoding it:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=5:5:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -preset fast -c:a copy output.mp4
```

## Faster

You could encode the ~20 segment conforming to the same parameters as the main input, then concatenate with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) in stream copy mode. However, this will be troublesome because conforming parameters is not trivial for most users, the concat `inpoint` directive is not guaranteed to seek accurately with non-intra inputs, and you could end up with timestamp issues anyway.

## Fastest

The most fastest way is to use a player to overlay the logo:

```
mpv --lavfi-complex="[vid1][vid2]overlay=5:5:enable='between(t,0,20)[vo]" video.mp4 --external-file=image.png
```