# Create drawbox with ffmpeg between specific seconds (without reencoding whole video - faster)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

My plan was to put a transparent red box behind a video. This box should only be present from second 1-45.
But if the videos are 3 hours long, the process takes a long time although it only has to process 45 seconds.

My first attempt takes too long:

`ffmpeg -i %1 -vf drawbox=0:9*ih/10:iw:ih/10:t=fill:color=red@0.5:enable='between(t,1,45)' "%~dp0transpred\%~n1%~x1`

Then i tried splitting the video into two parts. put the box on the first video, and then put the two back together again.

`ffmpeg  -ss 00:00:00.0000 -i %1 -to 00:00:45.0000  -vf drawbox=0:9*ih/10:iw:ih/10:t=fill:color=red@0.5:enable='between(t,1,45)' "%~dp0transpred\%~n1A%~x1"`

`FFMpeg -ss 00:00:45.0000 -i %1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero "%~dp0transpred\%~n1B%~x1"`

But i don't even have to try to put these two together, because they are not separated exactly at the second. I have read that this is due to "timestamps" and the different video and audio streams.

Now I'm trying an approach to create a stream with the bar, and then overlay it with the finished video. I haven't quite managed that yet, and I don't know if it's faster.
Shortening the video is very fast.

EDIT (Added as a replacement for the comment later)

Thanks for your help I have almost done it with a slightly different approach. Unfortunately, the second part now always has no sound. No matter if I put A and B (B no sound) or B and A (A no sound) together.

1. First split with mkvmerge so i have no worrys about the keyframes and get the exact time
   `mkvmerge --split timestamps:00:00:45.100 A.MKV -o splitmkm.mkv`
2. Then add the Bar (Black because of easier testing):
   `ffmpeg -i splitmkm-001.mkv -vf drawbox=0:9*ih/10:iw:ih/10:t=fill BAR1.MKV`
3. Merge (mkvmerge ends with error):
   `ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt -c copy output1.mkv`

EDIT (Answer to kesh)

This was the error `Again, audio codec config's must match across all your concat files`. The `drawbox` changed the audio Codec from AC-3 to Vorbis.

the procedure is now:

1. `mkvtoolnix\mkvmerge --split timestamps:00:00:05.100  %1 -o A_splitmkm.mkv` with mkvmerge i have an exact split at the time, and i don't have to learn about keyframes.
2. `ffmpeg -i A_splitmkm-001.mkv -vf drawbox=0:9*ih/10:iw:ih/10:t=fill:color=red A_BARmkm.MKV` create the Bar
3. `ffmpeg -i A_BARmkm.MKV -i A_splitmkm-001.mkv -map 0:v  -map 1 -map -1:v  -c copy A_BARwithAudio.mkv` redo the step with the changed audio from drawbox
4. `ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt -map 0  -c copy A_output1.mkv` merge

Now everything works.
Thanks alot!

Comment: How about creating a still transparent lavfi input and overlay it with the `enable` option?

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. 
i have so far found that your suggestion seems to be one of the better and quicker alternatives. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944118/fastest-way-to-add-image-into-video-using-ffmpeg-at-first-20-seconds) 
but i am still struggling with the implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
ffmpeg  -ss 00:00:00.0000 -to 00:00:45.0000 -i %1 \
        -vf "color=c=red:r=1:d=1[red];color=c=0x808080:r=1:d=1,format=y8,[red]alphamerge[fore]; \
            [fore][0:v]scale2ref=w=iw:h=ih/10[f][b]; \
            [b][f]overlay=0:H-h:enable='between(t,1,45)'" \
        "%~dp0transpred\%~n1A%~x1"
```

- `color=c=red` line: form an unsized red semi-transparent box which lasts for 1 frame over 1 second
- `[fore][back]scale2ref` line: size the red box to the frame
- `[b][f]overlay` line: apply the red box when needed

Because the stream foreground stream (which ends with `[f]`) only lasts for 1 frame, ffmpeg will only compute the box once, and `overlay` filter will reuse that frame until all the input video frames are processed.

On `drawbox`. Because you need a filled box, the above is simpler implementation IMO. If you need a boundary, the issue I faced is that it is incompatible with a transparent frame. This restriction makes it unusable with the preforming approach. [edit: to make `drawbox` to work with transparent frames, you need to set the option `replace=1`]

On your alternate splicing approach, if you cut your video at a keyframe, you should be able to make it to work. To find the keyframes, you need to use `ffprobe`. If you want to pursue this one, see [my recent answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71640052/4516027).

Comment: Thanks for your help I have almost done it with a slightly different approach. Unfortunately, the second part now always has no sound. No matter if I put A and B (B no sound) or B and A (A no sound) together. //
1. First split with mkvmerge so i have no worrys about the keyframes and get the exact time "mkvmerge --split timestamps:00:00:45.100 A.MKV -o splitmkm.mkv" //Then add the Bar (Black because of easier testing): "ffmpeg -i splitmkm-001.mkv -vf drawbox=0:9*ih/10:iw:ih/10:t=fill BAR1.MKV" //Merge (mkvmerge ends with error):"ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt  -c copy output1.mkv"

Comment: First, you should edit your post to convey the new development as it is hard to read it in the comment section. Second, when you say 'no sound` do you mean some files listed in `list.txt` has no sound while the others do? If so, concat demuxer may not like that. Add (matching) audio stream to the clips w/out sound with `-f lavfi -i anullsrc` audio input and `-shortest` output option. Again, audio codec config's must match across all your concat files.